# array or array SQL

Tags: sql

In my table I have this rows

```
    id   name           description cate_id   ver_id language
    1   producto1   breve descripcion   1       1     es-ES
    2   producto2   otra descripción    1       2     es-ES
    3   producto3   otra cosa           2       1       es-ES
```

Is posible create a sql query to return for example

```
[1]
 1  producto1   breve descripcion   1       1     es-ES
 2  producto2   otra descripción    1       2     es-ES

[2]
 3  producto3   otra cosa           2       1       es-ES
```

where [1] and [2] is cate_id?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean two different tables or grouped by cate_id?

Comment: hi @Dom I mean is one table, but the result of the query has to return something like [cate_id=1] all rows with cate_id=1 [cate_id=2] all rows with cate_id=2. in the same result. It is posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are literally trying to return 5 rows with different numbers of columns (1 column in the first row, 6 columns in the second and third row etc) then no, this is not possible.  If this is something you want to do, return the results you want ordered by `cate_id` and then format the data however you would like in the business or display layers.